# Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined if form is inside a div with ng-if condition

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-validation

I have a **form inside a div with ng-if** condition. Initially form is closed. On click a button, form is displayed. But on submitting form, I'm getting `Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined` error. If I **change ng-if into ng-show, it works perfect**. But I must have to use ng-if. I can't find reason of error. And one more thing that, on getting error, I'm also getting **form object as null**. If any one knows the answer, it will be appreciated.

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div id="addCommentDiv" ng-if="showAddCommentForm == true">
    <form id="formAddComment" name="formAddComment" novalidate>
        <textarea id="taAddComment" name="taAddComment" placeholder="Add a comment.." ng-model="new_comment" ng-maxlength="1000" ng-required="true"></textarea>
        <button type="button" ng-click="addComment()" ng-disabled="addCommentDisabled">Ok</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.addCommentDisabled = false;
$scope.addComment = function () {
    if ($scope.formAddComment.$valid) {
        console.log('valid');
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/turinggroup/angular-validator/issues/14). My issue is also same.

Comment: But I have not used that library. I have used only angularjs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass the form in addComment - 
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5vxffLa/)

```
$scope.addComment = function (formAddComment) {
 console.log('valid');
 if (formAddComment.$valid) {
    console.log('valid');
 }
}

 <button type="button" ng-click="addComment(formAddComment)" ng-disabled="addCommentDisabled">Ok</button>
```

Comment: can you explain that why I need to pass form in this case?

Comment: you can go through this link - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf ...

Comment: Thanks Disha, it works good!

@AkshayVaghasiya because ng-if creates new scope

Answer (score 0):

**ng-if** condition doesn't add the components into the DOM until condition is satisfied whereas the **ng-show** add the the component in DOM and when condition is satisfied, it displays.
So ,that's the reason it is giving error as it is not available  on the DOM.

Comment: @AnchalGupta, I know that. But there must be some solution as google team must have concerned that issue. Do you know the solution or alternate way? I have tried to recompile that div element. But still same problem.